# Best way to create a mongo expression that never matches

Tags: mongodb

What I am looking for is somehow the equivalent of doing in SQL:

```
WHERE 1 = 0
```

I'm looking for such a thing because I'm building a typesafe DSL to perform queries on my domain, supporting conjunctions and disjunctions. Sometimes it may be easier to add a query that never match anything, instead of dealing with it in the code.

For exemple, in my usecase:

```
StampleFilters().underCategoryIds(sharedCategoryIds.toList)
```

In this case, it does not work as expected because `sharedCategoryIds` is empty, so it results in a query being `$()`, which does not filter anything.
For an empty list, I would rather build a query that never returns anything.

Is there an easy way to do such a thing, without any impact on performances?

I could probably add some query like `{ somefield: unexistingvalue }` but I wonder if there is nothing better.

**Edit**

I expect the expression to be composable. I mean it should work in queries like `$or(exp1,exp2,exp3)` where `exp1` is for exemple the expression that never match.

If you have any proposition, it would be nice to explain why one is better than others and how it affect the query engine performances (or not)

Comment: there's no expression `x` you can "compose" into a filter like `$or(True, x)` which would make it false. Perhaps you mean `$and(...)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the best way to achieve what you want is to add `{_id : -1}`

`db.coll.find({a : 1})` will be transformed into `db.coll.find({a : 1, _id : -1})`. This is simpler then all shx2 solutions (except of the last one with noScan which is nice).

Moreover `_id` field is already a primary index, so it will quickly realize that there is no such `_id` field in the collection.

**P.S.** if someone would be so smart to name their _id as -1, then you can do `{_id : NaN}`.
If there will be `_id = NaN` then you most probably need to redevelop your app.

Comment: Except that it's perfectly valid to have a doc with `_id: -1`.

Comment: @JohnnyHK yes, I know. But how often have you seen _id : -1 in mongo applications? If you really think that it is probable to have it, how about _id : NaN?

Comment: `_id: NaN` seems like a better option.  Good idea.

Comment: @JohnnyHK that's right but I'm using a Scala MongoDB driver Casbah and have no idea how to use it to query for `Nan`

Comment: @SebastienLorber so use -1, -10000, 0, or just ask how to use casbah for NaN.

Comment: yes, I've come up using `id = 1 and id= -1`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24207311/problems-using-nothing-bottom-type-while-trying-to-create-generic-zeros-for-para

Answer (score 2):

I came up with a few ways to achieve that:

1. "P&!P": `{ $and: [ {X:0}, {X:{$ne:0}} ] }`
2. Can't be "$in" an empty list: `{ X: {$in: []} }`
3. Nothing can be this long `{ X: {$size: 9999999999999999} }`
4. "[noScan](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/maxScan/)": `db.coll.find({})._addSpecial("$maxScan", 0)`

EDIT:

- one more, using `$where`: `{ $where: function() {return 0} }`

Comment: Actually as my expression is supposed to be "composable" into `$and` and `$or` expressions, the last solution with maxScan won't work for me as it always returns nothing globally

Comment: @SebastienLorber I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "composable", but solutionw 1-3 are mere filter-expressions.

Comment: yes 1-3 is ok for me, as we can put these expressions with $and or $or . But any idea of the performance/optimizer impact of these?

Comment: @SebastienLorber, except for possibly #4, they are surely slower than salvador's `_id=NaN` (assuming you didn't drop the default index on `_id`). (unless mongodb is very clever at figuring out the query can't possibly return results. I don't know if it is).